# sed not removing all whitespaces from the beginning of each line in the file

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I have few lines code as below:

```
bash-3.2$ cat remove_space.txt
    this is firs line with 2-3 spaces
                    2nd line with more space, this is where the issue is.
          3rd line
```

I am able to suppress the leading whitespaces from the beginning of each line but not from 2nd line. I am not getting why `sed` is failing there.

```
bash-3.2$ sed 's/^ *//g' remove_space.txt
this is firs line with 2-3 spaces
                2nd line with more space, this is where the issue is.
3rd line


bash-3.2$
```

#### Update

```
with `-vte` 

bash-3.2$ cat -vte remove_space.txt
    this is firs line with 2-3 spaces$
    ^I^I^I^I2nd line with more space, this is where the issue is.$
          3rd line $
$
$
bash-3.2$
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your command works as expected on GNU `sed 4.2.2`. What version are you trying this on? and can you check on your file for DOS style line terminators? Post the output of `file remove_space.txt`

Comment: I am executing this command from a Mac, could it be cause of it ? Because from search I got to know like GNU sed and sed in Mac are different.

Comment: Yes they are different, the FreeBSD `sed` might require `-e` i.e as `sed -e ..`

Comment: I have tried with `-e` flag but still same result.

Comment: Could you use `od -c` command or `cat -vTE` to check if your spaces are actually spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is because your file contains some `\t` in the beginning of the lines as shown by `cat -vTE` (as requested in my comment)

```
bash-3.2$ cat -vte remove_space.txt
    this is firs line with 2-3 spaces$
    ^I^I^I^I2nd line with more space, this is where the issue is.$
          3rd line $
```

You can change your command into:

```
sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]+//' remove_space.txt
```

to take care of the `spaces` and the `tabs`. Also for portability reasons use `POSIX` regex as defined in the help https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1

> ```
>  -E        Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular
>    expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).  The
>    re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The second line has TAB characters after the first 4 spaces -- that's what `^I` signifies. You're only removing spaces, not TAB.

```
sed $'s/^[ \t]*//' remove_space.txt
```

BTW, there's no need to use the `g` modifiers when a pattern is anchored with `^` or `$`. These patterns can only match once on a line.

Comment: Is there a reason there is a `$` before your sed search and replace command?

Comment: Yes, it's needed to translate the `\t` escape sequence to a TAB character.

Comment: Your answer using `[[:space:]]` is better, though.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that `$`

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting

Comment: Thanks for the link as well! I really appreciate. Just an additional question Barmar if you don't mind, do you think this works also on `FreeBSD/MacOS` `sed` utility?

Comment: @Allan Yes, that's where I tested it.

Comment: I hope one day I can reach your level! ;-) Have a nice day and thank you for the tips/hints.

Answer (score 2):

The four `^I` in the second line are tabulations, those are the whitespace characters that still appear in your output.

I suggest you use the following command to remove any kind of space from the beginning of the lines :

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//' remove_space.txt
```

Comment: You can escape `+` in your previous answer or use the extended regex mode via `-E`. Anyway +1!

Comment: @Allan The `\+` would only for GNU sed from what I could tell (didn't work with the `--posix` flag), and I really doubt it provides a significant performance boost. If I overcome my laziness I'll start by testing whether it does :)

Comment: If everything could be GNU based the world would be better in my opinion... Anyway!